# What percentage of COVID-19 cases are contracted during a hospital stay as a patient?

Tags: covid-19, hospital

I read on https://www.20minutes.fr/arts-stars/culture/2759843-20200413-coronavirus-comedien-maurice-barrier-mort-covid-19 ([mirror](http://archive.is/9SK7R)):

> Le comédien Maurice Barrier est mort du Covid-19. [Il] a attrapé le coronavirus lors d’un séjour à l’hôpital, selon son entourage

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Le%20com%C3%A9dien%20Maurice%20Barrier%20est%20mort%20du%20Covid-19.%20Il%20a%20attrap%C3%A9%20le%20coronavirus%20lors%20d%E2%80%99un%20s%C3%A9jour%20%C3%A0%20l%E2%80%99h%C3%B4pital%2C%20selon%20son%20entourage):

> Comedian Maurice Barrier died of the Covid-19. [He] caught the coronavirus during a hospital stay, according to his entourage.

What percentage of COVID-19 cases are  contracted during a hospital stay as a patient?

---

A few studies have looked at the percentage of COVID-19 cases  contracted by medical workers, e.g. https://www.opb.org/news/article/coronavirus-covid-19-data-health-care-medical-workers-infection/:

> Ohio, on the other hand, reported at least 16% of its cases involved health care workers, while in Minnesota, it was 28% on Wednesday.
>
> Other countries are reporting COVID-19’s impact on their health care community. Spain has said at least 12,298 health care workers have tested positive for the disease – 14.4% of the total reported cases. More than 60 doctors have died in Italy.

This number can be high due to PPE shortage, e.g. https://www.theverge.com/2020/3/5/21166088/coronavirus-covid-19-protection-doctors-nurses-health-workers-risk:

> Less than a third of nurses in the US work at health care facilities with enough PPE to handle an outbreak of COVID-19, according to a survey from the union National Nurses United.

In this question I would like to concentrate on hospital stay as a patient.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNrvAB)

Comment: Which hospital are you asking about?

Comment: @GrahamChiu curious worldwide

Comment: And did you do any research at all?

Comment: @GrahamChiu yes but so far I could only find infection of medical workers, not patients. Let's add patients in the question.

Comment: So how about summarising the data you have found regarding the infection of medical staff?

Comment: @GrahamChiu sure done